# Expand org-mode * Tasks

Tags: org-mode

I'm new to emacs and playing around with `org-mode`. I have a text file that looks like this:

```
* Tasks
** task 1
** task 2
** TODO task 3
** DONE task 4
** TODO task 5
```

I open it with emacs and then go into `org-mode`.

Then it ends up looking like this:

```
* Tasks...
```

How do I expand the list?

Comment: [Visibility cycling](http://orgmode.org/manual/Visibility-cycling.html#Visibility-cycling) in org-mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the TAB key on the "Task" headline to cycle visibility.

If you want the node to develop automatically when you open your org file, you can also set the `VISIBILITY` property of the node to `children` for such as in the following example:

```
 * Tasks
 :PROPERTIES:
 :VISIBILITY: children
 :END:
** task 1
** task 2
```